# Android - Graying out/changing the alpha of all items aside from the selected item

Tags: android, listview

Good day. I have an android application which displays a `ListView`. Upon clicking the any of the rows, I want all other rows to be grayed out. I am using a custom `ListView` with my own `BaseAdapter` and I know I can create an onclick function on the `getView` function there. However, doing so invalidates the `onItemClick` function I have in my base activity that's why I want to do this in my base activity as much as possible.

Here is how I made my `onItemClick` function:

```
resultListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resultListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, 0);
        resultListView.setClickable(false);
        resultListView.setScrollContainer(false);
        resultListView.setEnabled(false);

        };

    });
}
```

Is there a way to gray out all the other items except for the chosen item? Even changing the alpha/lowering it would help. I want to give the user an impression that the other list items are not clickable. I'm currently having a tough time figuring it out. Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

I am able to adjust the alpha by doing:

```
resultListView.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
```

However, it affects the whole row and I am unable to adjust the alpha for the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Create class to hold variables. Pass this class to the adapter instead of string for example. Create a boolean variable isSelected in your class. Set isSelected in onItemClick(), and enable/disable the views from getView() depending on your isSelected variable.

Comment: I know I can use by custom Base Adapter to store a variable/boolean to check if a certain item is selected and change the background color/alpha based on the boolean variable. However, my listview can contains ten thousand+ items at once and doing that will consume a lot of processing time that's why I wanted to resort to using the view instead.

Comment: If I recall correctly (which I may not) getView () recycles views in a way that it is not called on views that are not visible.

Comment: Sorry I do not get why your clarification is necessary. What I want to achieve is to change the alpha of the listView while keeping the alpha of the selected item.

Comment: getView will not be called on your thousand plus items, only on the visible items, making the overhead potentially negligible. I think you will have to loop over your data set to set the alpha of every item if you do not want to do that, which I would imagine would use more processing power. EDIT: Wait are you trying to set the alpha of the listview itself, and not it's children?

Comment: I'll look into using the BaseAdapter Properly as it seems to be the best and most elegant used. Also, I was trying to set the alpha of the children, I realized my mistake when I adjusted the alpha of the listview.